# R: How to fix median labels in side-by-side boxplots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a boxplot where each categorical variable on the x-axis has 2 corresponding box plots (side-by-side). I am trying to label the median bar, but the labels come out stacked rather than side by side -- image below for reference.

How can I move the top label to the left and the bottom label to the right along the x-axis? My code is below, I've tried a wide variety of position nudges and v values with no success.

```
 ggplot() + 
   geom_boxplot(data = data, aes(x = cat_var, y = value, fill=status), alpha = 0.3) +
   scale_y_log10() +
   facet_wrap(~cat_var2) +
   scale_fill_manual(values=cat.colors) +
   geom_text(data = labs2, aes(x = cat_var, y = med, label = med), position = 
   position_nudge(x=0.05, y=.05))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same `position` as `geom_boxplot`, which by default is `position_dodge2`. You don't need a separate labels data frame; you can use `stat = "summary"` inside `geom_text` to get the label positions:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = cat_var, y = value, fill = status)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun = "median", vjust = -0.5,
            position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8),
            aes(label = round(after_stat(y)))) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~cat_var2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cat.colors)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

It took more work to create a data set with the same structure as your own as it did to answer the question. Please try to make questions *reproducible*. The data set used in the plot above was created as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

data <- expand.grid(cat_var = factor(c("Less than 3km away", 
                                       "3 - 5km away",
                                        "More than 5km away"),
                                     c("Less than 3km away", 
                                       "3 - 5km away",
                                       "More than 5km away")),
                    cat_var2 = c("High", "Moderate", "None"),
                    status = c("Impact Sector", "Non-Impact Sector")) %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  reframe(value = rgamma(100, 3, 1e-4) + 1000)

cat.colors <- c("dodgerblue", "limegreen")
```